# Saving list values when terminating

Tags: python, python-3.x, save

I am doing some tests: running time functions and appending values to a list.

I am not really sure what to receive. I am thinking about cancelling the shell after a period of time. However, I would like to see what values were appended to the list. Is there any pythonic way to do this, or is the best way to save data to a txt file?

Comment: Umm, so let's say you have list like `my_list = [ "content" ]`. To display it you just have to do `print(str(my_list))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need the output to be robust to random shutdowns and/or crashes, you should write each entry to file as they are generated instead of appending to a list (assuming you don't need them in the program). And if you do it using `with open(...) as f:` then it will handle closing the file appropriately even with unexpected shutdowns.

Alternatively, if you write the list as a class attribute, and the class instance is in the global namespace, it will still exist after you cancel the program and you can access it manually then. That's not very pretty though, and is problematic if anyone else touches your program, or if you come back to it later.

Or perhaps the best option would be to add an appropriate stopping condition and avoid having to terminate your program.